# After removing autopublish, how do I read Meter.user().services?

Tags: javascript, meteor, google-oauth, facebook-oauth

Before I removed the autopublish package from my project `meteor remove autopublish`,
I was able to read in the oAuth services that the logged in user was using, e.g. 
 `var facebookSignIn = Meteor.user().services.facebook;` or

```
var googleSignIn = Meteor.user().services.google;
```

The reason this is important, is because I would use this `googleSignIn` or `facebookSignIn` information  to determine how to save the logged-in users personal details, such as their: name, email, and profile picture. 
In code:

```
var facebookSignIn = Meteor.user().services.facebook;
var googleSignIn = Meteor.user().services.google;
var ownderId = Meteor.user()._id;

if (facebookSignIn) {
        console.log("Its a Facebook Account Sign in!");
        var userName = Meteor.user().services.facebook.name;
        var emailAdress =  Meteor.user().services.facebook.email;
        var facebookProfilePic = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + user.services.facebook.id + "/picture/?type=large"; 
    }
else if (googleSignIn) {
        console.log("Its a Google Account Sign in!");
        var userName = Meteor.user().services.google.name;
        var emailAdress =  Meteor.user().services.google.email;
        var googleProfilePic = Meteor.user().services.google.picture;

    }
else {  
        console.log("Your not Signed in!");
    }
```

How do I retrieve `Meteor.user().services.facebook` and `Meteor.user().services.google` now that I have removed the autopublish package?

In the browser console (main.js:1140), this error message appears:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'facebook' of undefined
```

The code in on main.js: 1140 is:

```
var facebookSignIn = Meteor.user().services.facebook;
```

Comment: Have you done a publish of Meteor.users on the server? ```Meteor.publish("userPublication", function publishFunction(){
      return Meteor.users.find();
  });```

Comment: @blueren Thanks i followed your advise and published this on the server and it worked!

Comment: Good to know. I'll just leave that as an answer to your question.

Comment: Make those decisions on the server. The `services` key includes private data that should not be published (hashed passwords, resume tokens...)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to first publish the collection from the server, in order for the collection to be made available in the client (which in turn must subscribe to the published collection)

```
Meteor.publish("userPublication", function publishFunction(){ 
       return Meteor.users.find(); })
```